# Communicate with Xposed module (Set values inside xposed hook)

Tags: android, setvalue, xposed

How can I manipulate/set variables inside my Xposed hooks from an outside application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver in a hook, which can then be used to manipulate values inside the running system via broadcast Intents. It works!